# The fileuploaded is always null when using p:fileUploaded

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

When using fileUpload from primefaces5.0, the file uploaded is always null.

The View :

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data"  style="text-align:center;">
    <p:fileUpload value="#{noteController.fileName}" mode="simple" skinSimple="true" />
    <p:commandButton  class="btn btn-success" value="Upload file" ajax="false"  actionListener="#{noteController.upload}" />
</h:form>
```

ManagedBean :

```
@ManagedBean( name = "noteController")
@ApplicationScoped
public class NoteController {
    private UploadedFile fileName;
    public String upload(){
        if(fileName != null) {
           return "success";
        }
        return "error";
    }
public UploadedFile getFileName() {
    return fileName;
}

public void setFileName(UploadedFile fileName) {
    this.fileName = fileName;
}
}
```

And the web.xml, I add this :

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.UPLOADER</param-name>
    <param-value>commons</param-value>
</context-param>

<filter>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter
    </filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

As result : fileName is always null, and the view is not redirected to the error's view. The view remains at the same page when the action upload is trigged.

Answer (score 0):

Remove skinSimple="true", this worked for me.
Anyhow, still trying to find the reason...